# The sidebar recent blog link goes to the mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, blog, sidebar

The sidebar link to the most recent blog post:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/?cb=1

includes `?cb=1`, which appears to cause the mobile site to appear on the desktop. When I remove the parameter, I am returned to the regular (desktop) site.

I am running Chrome 37 and `window.innerWidth` returns `1366`.

Comment: The `?cb=1` indicates that you clicked the link from the Community Bulletin, and has nothing to do with the fact that you see the mobile version. When I click that link, I get the desktop version.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: Not for me. When I append `?cb=1`, I get the mobile version, when I remove it, I get the desktop version. Even on a different browser without a SE login. I’m on Debian, tested with Firefox and Chromium. -- Clicking at "Exit the Mobile Edition" doesn’t work, only removing this parameter leads me to the desktop version.

Comment: Even when I click "Exit the Mobile Edition," I am still presented with the mobile version. `window.innerWidth` returns `1366`, if this contributes to a pattern.

Comment: This is flip-flopping for me now. Just now I got the mobile version. I found a duplicate post, VtCed your question, then clicked the links again *and now I get the Desktop version again*. Window size does not appear to have any influence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please note that "Exit the Mobile Edition" has **no effect** on what version I get.

Comment: Probable cause: a race condition **on the Wordpress side**. Someone *else* is accessing the site from a mobile device, and *other* people visiting at around the same time get the mobile version served.

Comment: Reproduced the problem by using a mobile device to follow the same link. To get back to the desktop version, it appears to using the *exit mobile version* link **on your mobile device** also lets desktop browsers see the site again.

Comment: This is probably limited to users on the same shared IP address; the Wordpress plugin storing the info per IP address would make more sense than this to be stored globally (you'd see more random flipflopping).

Comment: Nobody else uses my ip address, and I have not visited the SE blog from a mobile device. Would this info is stored server-side for several months?

Comment: @Mooseman: I don't know; I'm merely speculating as to its cause. That I can reproduce the problem now at will does tell me I'm on to something here.